# error 404 in vue with php

Tags: vue.js, post, http, axios

He creado un proyecto con vue-cli y estoy haciendo peticiones a una archivo .php del cual al hacer la petición me devuelve un **error 404**

No se que estoy haciendo mal, si alguien me podría echar una mano se lo agradecería.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Error 404 , es ruta no encontrada, verifica que la ruta existe.

Comment: sisi he verificado la ruta y no encuentro cual es el problema y aún poniendo la ruta desde http:localhost hasta le archivo .php me sigue devolviendo un error 404

Comment: verifica el estado de tu servidor web, consultando a otra pagina.

Comment: es en localhost estoy haciendo pruebas de momento, ya he probado en incognito y tampoco se porque me da ese error si el archivo está

Comment: Aunque sea en localhost deberías tener un server WEB el cual podrías verificar.

Comment: sugieres que utilice express ?